# Splitting a string in arguments (using sed/awk)

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh, tokenize

Environment: KornShell (ksh)

I want to separate the string below:

```
-ssRMDFXXRT -rtETL -ltDAILY -sD20120203 -lfRS -UP"EffTimeStamp=20110203-210000#InputCtxNm=Forigen Exchange Today#RunType=EOD" -QqDESKTOP -Ln9999 -XmXMLBLOCK
```

And output should be (string after -UP should remain as one single token):

```
-ssRMDFXXRT 
-rtETL 
-ltDAILY 
-sD20120203 
-lfRS 
-UP"EffTimeStamp=20110203-210000#InputCtxNm=Forigen Exchange Today#RunType=EOD" 
-QqDESKTOP 
-Ln9999 
-XmXMLBLOCK
```

I tried a lot but could not get the expected output, but now I think I need some help. Please help.

Comment: Do you maybe want to parse the arguments passed to your script?

Answer (score 1):

```
for arg in "$@"; do printf '<%s>\n' "$arg"; done
```

This iterates over all arguments and does not break arguments at spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
krithika.542> echo "-ssRMDFXXRT -rtETL -ltDAILY -sD20120203 -lfRS -UP"EffTimeStamp=20110203-210000#InputCtxNm=Forigen Exchange Today#RunType=EOD" -QqDESKTOP -Ln9999 -XmXMLBLOCK" | perl -pe 's/ /\n/g'
-ssRMDFXXRT
-rtETL
-ltDAILY
-sD20120203
-lfRS
-UPEffTimeStamp=20110203-210000#InputCtxNm=Forigen
Exchange
Today#RunType=EOD
-QqDESKTOP
-Ln9999
-XmXMLBLOCK
krithika[ncm_o12.0_int.cctcsvibh].543>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use eval to get the shell to respect the quoted argument

```
$ str='-ssRMDFXXRT -rtETL -ltDAILY -sD20120203 -lfRS -UP"EffTimeStamp=20110203-210000#InputCtxNm=Forigen Exchange Today#RunType=EOD" -QqDESKTOP -Ln9999 -XmXMLBLOCK'
$ arr=($str); echo ${#arr[@]}
11
$ arr=("$str"); echo ${#arr[@]}
1
$ eval arr=($str); echo ${#arr[@]}
9
```

Then to display by line: `printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"`
You'll notice the double quotes have vanished from the "complex" argument.

But, your initial string is not `"$*"` right? If it is, use `"$@"` instead.